# Prove that every compact space is homeomorphic to a compact set in some power of the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On page 45 of V. Bogachev's "Real and Functional Analysis", we see the following exercise (1.9.76),

Prove that every compact space is homeomorphic to a compact set in some power of the interval $[0,1]$.

My question: If every compact space $A$ were homeomorphic to a compact subspace of $[0,1]^J$ for some $J$, would it not also follow that $A$ is Hausdorff since $A$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of the Hausdorff space $[0,1]^J$? But obviously not every compact space is Hausdorff, a contradiction. So I am not quite sure how to proceed with this exercise.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly this. From Wikipedia: “ Some branches of mathematics such as algebraic geometry, typically influenced by the French school of Bourbaki, use the term quasi-compact for the general notion, and reserve the term compact for topological spaces that are both Hausdorff and quasi-compact. A compact set is sometimes referred to as a compactum, plural compacta.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I just double checked his definition of compactness and it does indeed assume the Hausdorff condition. I was not expecting this since I studied topology from Munkres and he distinguishes very clearly between compact sets and Hausdorff sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space):

> Some branches of mathematics such as algebraic geometry, typically influenced by the French school of Bourbaki, use the term quasi-compact for the general notion, and reserve the term compact for topological spaces that are both Hausdorff and quasi-compact.